# Integrate React router active NavLink with child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My menu currently looks like this:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem text="link1" />
    <MenuItem text="link2" />
</Menu>
```

To integrate with `react-router-dom`, I modified in the following way:

```
<Menu>

    <NavLink to="link1">
        <MenuItem text="link1" />
    </NavLink>

    <NavLink to="link2">
        <MenuItem text="link2" />
    </NavLink>

</Menu>
```

My `MenuItem` Component supports styling of the currently "active" link like so:

```
<MenuItem active text="link1" />
```

How do I integrate the "active" route styling with `react-router-dom` ?

Is there some boolean I can set in the following way?

```
<MenuItem active={isRouteActive} text="link1" />
```

**Edit:** [`MenuItem`](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v2/#core/components/menu.menu-item) is a component from Blueprintjs. When the `active` prop is set, its possible some internal styling rules are applied to the component. I could use the `activeClassName` prop on `NavLink` but I don't want to replicate the css of a 3rd party component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. I created my own Component using composition of the `Route` component

```
const MenuItemExt = ({ icon, text, to, activeOnlyWhenExact }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={to}
      exact={activeOnlyWhenExact}
      children={({match, history}) => (
        <MenuItem
          active={match}
          icon={icon}
          onClick={() => {
            history.push(to);
          }}
          text={text}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: This is a simpler, more concise answer than the accepted.

Comment: This breaks for Submenu's that the MenuItem supports, when you can use the text property. `text={ (true)? (<NavLink to="/applications/home">Applications</NavLink>):(<span>Test</span>)}`

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this is used, for instance how do you obtain `activeOnlyWhenExact` ?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, NavLink from rr4 doesn't offer a way to pass `isActive` info to its children(MenuItem) for now.

Good thing is rr4 takes component centric approach so that literally everything is just react component, NavLink by itself is juts a custom component composed of:

- `<Route/>` (handles route matching)
- `<Link/>` (dispaches route action)

We can create our version of custom link sort like:

```
const NavLink = ({
  to,
  children,
  className,
  activeClassName,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const path = typeof to === "object" ? to.pathname : to;
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      children={({ match }) => {
        const isActive = !!match;
        return (
          <Link
            {...rest}
            className={
              isActive
               ? [className, activeClassName].filter(i => i).join(" ")
               : className
            }
            to={to}
          >
            {typeof children === 'function' ? children(isActive) : children}
          </Link>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default NavLink;
```

and then use it as:

```
<Menu>
  <NavLink to="link1">
    {isActive => <MenuItem active={isActive} text="link1" />}
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink to="link2">
    {isActive => <MenuItem active={isActive} text="link2" />}
  </NavLink>
</Menu>
```

This uses [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to share isActive state from parent to child. This should just work fine, but to fully mimic the way (e.g, accessibility support) NavLink works in rr4, patch it based on its [implementation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js) might still needed.

For this specific case, use local state w/ Link might be easier

```
state = { activeLink: '' }
render() {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <Link to='link1' onClick={() => this.setState({ activeLink: 'link1' })>
        <MenuItem active={this.state.activeLink === 'link1'} text='link1' />
      </Link>
      <Link to='link2' onClick={() => this.setState({ activeLink: 'link2' })>
        <MenuItem active={this.state.activeLink === 'link2'} text='link2' />
      </Link>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found another way using children prop of NavLink:

```
<NavLink children={({ isActive }) => (
      <MenuItem isActive={isActive}/>
   )}
/>
```

Using react router 6. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have 2 routes:

/admin

/admin/privileges

You want navbar text "Admin" to be active-coloured when either of the above links is open. You could achieve this with something like this:

```
<NavLink
            exact
            to="/admin"
            className="..."
            activeClassName="..."
            isActive={(match, location) => {
              let pathStrings = location.pathname.split('/');

// pathstrings will be ['/', 'admin', '/', 'privileges']
// should you add a new subroute, say /admin/locations/ the code would still work


              if (match) {
                return true;
              } else if (pathStrings[1] === 'admin') {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            }}
          >
            Admin
          </NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use props `activeClassName` from react router.

```
<NavLink activeClassName="custom-active-class" to="link1">
    <MenuItem className="custom-link-class" text="link1" />
</NavLink>

<NavLink activeClassName="custom-active-class" to="link2">
    <MenuItem className="custom-link-class" text="link2" />
</NavLink>
```

and change little bit your css

`.custom-active-class .custom-link-class{
   background-color: red;
}`

Comment: I won't be able to do that. `MenuItem` is not a component I coded. It's from a UI library called blueprintjs.

Comment: can you write custom css ?

Comment: i edited my answers. You can do that with add the custom css `.custom-active-class .custom-link-class{
   background-color: red;
}`

Comment: `MenuItem` has its own css which gets added when `active` is set. So yes, I could write custom css to match `MenuItem`'s internal styling but that seems like a hacky way to do so. I'd like an easy way to toggle the `active` prop

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach; if you're looping over an array of navlinks and need a dynamic check;

```
// Routes
<Route exact path="/news" component={News} />
<Route path="/news/:nid" component={NewsDetails} />

{this.state.navItems.auth.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index} className="nav-item">
      <NavLink
        exact
        to={item.path}
        className="nav-link"
        activeClassName="active"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        isActive={(match, location) => {
          if (match) {
            return true;
          }

          if (location.pathname.indexOf(item.path) > -1) {
            // Prevent home from matching
            if (item.path !== '/') {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }}>
        ...
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of awesome answers here. Here's what i ended up making based off these suggestions, Also added multiple paths via an array which is pretty cool. Think you need at least v4 to do this

```
    <Route
                path={['/app/discover', '/app/discover', '/app/engage']}
                exact={false}
                children={({ match, history }) => (
                    <Tab
                        handleClick={() => {
                            if (userCan(perms.TRENDS_READ)) {
                                history.push(routes.app.discover.trends.path)
                            } else {
                                history.push(routes.app.engage.lists.lists.path)
                            }
                        }}
                        tabImage={
                            <OutcomeImage
                                className={'opacityOneHover'}
                                fill='white'
                                opacity={match ? 1 : 0.5}
                            />
                        }
                    />
                )}
            />
```